# Sum of two squares in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have written a code based on the two pointer algorithm to find the sum of two squares. My problem is that I run into a memory error when running this code for an input `n=55555**2 + 66666**2`. I am wondering how to correct this memory error.

```
def sum_of_two_squares(n):
    look=tuple(range(n))
    i=0
    j = len(look)-1
    while i < j:
        x = (look[i])**2 + (look[j])**2
        if x == n:
            return (j,i)
        elif x < n:
            i += 1
        else:
            j -= 1
    return None

n=55555**2 + 66666**2
print(sum_of_two_squares(n))
```

The problem Im trying to solve using two pointer algorithm is:
return a tuple of two positive integers whose squares add up to n, or return None if the integer n cannot be so expressed as a sum of two squares. The returned tuple must present the larger of its two numbers first. Furthermore, if some integer can be expressed as a sum of two squares in several ways, return the breakdown that maximizes the larger number. For example, the integer 85 allows two such representations `7*7 + 6*6` and `9*9 + 2*2`, of which this function must therefore return (9, 2).

Comment: No, it has to return the base

Comment: What is the difference between two successive squares?

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a tuple of size 55555^2 + 66666^2 = 7530713581

So if each element of the tuple takes one byte, the tuple will take up 7.01 GiB.

You'll need to either reduce the size of the tuple, or possibly make each element take up less space by specifying the type of each element: I would suggest looking into Numpy for the latter.

---

Specifically for this problem:

#### Why use a tuple at all?

You create the variable `look` which is just a list of integers:

```
look=tuple(range(n))  # = (0, 1, 2, ..., n-1)
```

Then you reference it, but never modify it. So: `look[i] == i` and  `look[j] == j`.

So you're looking up numbers in a list of numbers.  Why look them up?  Why not just use `i` in place of `look[i]` and remove `look` altogether?

Comment: That's where I am challenged. I tried taking the square root of (n) and still cant solve this issue. Any suggestions to reduce the size of the tuple?

Comment: @Rcarit Why use a tuple at all? It seems like you're just storing a list of all the numbers in it and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the ranges at all, and certainly do not need to convert them into tuples. They take a ridiculous amount of space, but you only need their **current** elements, numbers `i` and `j`. Also, as the friendly commenter suggested, you can start with `sqrt(n)` to improve the performance further.

```
def sum_of_two_squares(n):
    i = 1
    j = int(n ** (1/2))

    while i < j:
        x = i * i + j * j
        if x == n:
            return j, i

        if x < n:
            i += 1
        else:
            j -= 1
```

Bear in mind that the problem takes a **very** long time to be solved. Be patient. And no, NumPy won't help. There is nothing here to vectorize.

Comment: I still get an error message saying it is too slow. There has to be another way to make it faster

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. There is no such error message in Python. And, as I said, it is a VERY time-consuming problem.

Comment: I have a tester code Im running it against and it says the function is rejected for being too slow. It also does not return None for an input of 1, so something in the logic has to be changed

Comment: Fixing the second problem is easy, just start with `i=1`. I have no idea about the tester code. You did not mention it in the question, and optimizing for speed would be a very different topic. In fact, it cannot be solved without having access to the tester.

Comment: Repacing the power operation with multiplication is going to help a bit. (See the edit.)

Comment: I can give you the tester code if you want it let me know

Comment: I don't think `int(n ** 1/2)` does what you intended here.

Comment: @MarkDickinson No, it doesn't. Fixed it.

Comment: Note that there is `math.isqrt` (which can handle arbitrarily large python integers) to avoid `int(n ** (1/2))` (which can only handle integers than can be converted to float, possibly with a big loss of precision). For instance `isqrt(9**34)**2 == 9**34` is True but `int((9**34)**0.5)**2 == 9**34` is False; and `isqrt(10**310)**2 == 10**310` is True but `int((10**310)**0.5)` raises OverflowError: int too large to convert to float.